# Extract values according to the result

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a dataframe that represents characteristics of people, such as occupation, gender, and telework use :

```
data = data.frame (profession = sample (c ("craftsman", "employee", "senior executive"), 10000, replace = TRUE), sex = sample (c ("M", "F"), 10000, replace = TRUE), en_teletjob = sample (c ("Yes", "No"), 10000, replace = TRUE))
```

I would like to create a new dataframe, resulting from an extraction of the values ​​of "data", such as:

- That there are 20% men and 80% women
- And, that there are 60% of craftsmen, 20% of employees, and 20% of senior executives
- And, that there be 50% of "Yes" to the use of telework.

Is it possible to do this on R?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, if any answers have solved your question, please mark your preferable one as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. Thank you!

Comment: Please do consider accepting answers if any of them solve your problem to your satisfaction. It is not required but it is helpful in signposting to others what has worked. You don't appear to have accepted any answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can try is next with `apply()` and `prop.table()` joint with `table()` in order to summarise all variables. Here the code:

```
#Code
apply(data,2,function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
```

Output:

```
$profession
x
       craftsman         employee senior executive 
          0.3331           0.3315           0.3354 

$sex
x
     F      M 
0.4987 0.5013 

$en_teletjob
x
   No   Yes 
0.503 0.497
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply()` to call `proportions()` on each variable. It returns a `list` object.

```
lapply(data, function(x) proportions(table(x)))

# $profession
# x
#        craftsman         employee senior executive 
#           0.3336           0.3318           0.3346 
# 
# $sex
# x
#      F      M 
# 0.5035 0.4965 
# 
# $en_teletjob
# x
#     No    Yes 
# 0.4978 0.5022
```

***Note:*** *`prop.table()` is an earlier name of `proportions()`, retained for back-compatibility.*

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse` would be to use `adorn_percentages`

-code

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
map(names(data),  ~data %>%
             select(.x) %>% 
             count(!! rlang::sym(.x)) %>% 
             adorn_percentages(denominator = 'col'))
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#       profession      n
#        craftsman 0.3302
#         employee 0.3320
# senior executive 0.3378

#[[2]]
# sex      n
#   F 0.5108
#   M 0.4892

#[[3]]
# en_teletjob      n
#          No 0.4981
#         Yes 0.5019
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which completely corresponds to my need. However, I'm having trouble seeing where to enter my percentage conditions (20% men, 80% women, etc). Where am I supposed to enter these parameters?
Thank you

Comment: @Préliator you don't need to enter any percentage conditions.  It calculates based on the frequency count from `count` step

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand. From what I understand, the algorithm that you gave me allows to calculate the proportions of modalities for each column. It's interesting, but these percentages don't suit me. How can I extract a dataframe that matches the parameters I gave above (a dataframe that contains 20% women and 80% men, 60% craftsmen 20% employees and 20% executives higher, and 50% of "yes" to the use of telework?